# Serializing String field as objectId field using mongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

Let's say i'm having a pojo

```
public class example{
    private String id;
    private String photoId
}
```

Now when saving an instance of this pojo, id is saved as objectId. I also want that photoId will be serialized as ObjectId. is there some kind of annotation that i can add to photoId
that will enable it?

```
public class example{
    @Id
    private String id; //default objectId serialization

    @MongoType(ObjectId.class) //not real annotation, looking for real one
    private String photoId; // enforce ObjectId serialization - what i want

mongoTemplate.insert(examplePojo); //will result as {_id :objectId(), photoId: objectId(...)}
```

----- EDIT ------
photoId is a string rep of objectId, example:

```
public void saveExample(String id, String photoId){
    Example example = new Example(id, photoId);
    mongoTemplate.insert(example);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Roy

Comment: Can the down voter please explain why? is there something unclear? does not show research? (if so please direct me to the relevant solution), unhelpful (I think it is helpful and it's something i'm trying to accomplish). anyhow it' really annoying that people downvoting without explaining how to improve the question. it just hurts the chance that someone will take the time to try and try to help me

Comment: It was a while ago, but did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @royB did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want that?

An Object Id is generated by mongodb with some additional information:

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
>
> 1. 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> 2. 3-byte machine identifier,
> 3. 2-byte process id, and
> 4. 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

There is no need to generate that on your side. But it is still possible to *override* that functionality.

From the spring-mongodb documentation:

> The following outlines what type conversion, if any, will be done on
>   the property mapped to the _id document field when using the
>   MappingMongoConverter, the default for MongoTemplate.
>
> - An id property or field declared as a **String** in the Java class will be converted to and stored as an ObjectId if possible using a Spring
>     Converter. Valid conversion rules are delegated to
>     the MongoDB Java driver. If it cannot be converted to an ObjectId,
>     then the value will be stored as a string in the database.
> - An id property or field declared as **BigInteger** in the Java class will be converted to and stored as an ObjectId using a Spring
>     Converter.

However you can write your own Converter for your own types.

Also change

`@MongoType(ObjectId.class)`to `@Id`. And make sure that your custom id has some value, if not mongodb will create an ObjectID for you.

Check also the mongodb [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) regarding ObjectIds.

**UPDATE**

The question now is how to handle references.

Here a little example from the manual.

```
@Document
public class Account {
 @Id
 private ObjectId id;
 private Float total;
}
@Document
public class Person {
 @Id
 private ObjectId id;
 @Indexed
 private Integer ssn;
 @DBRef
 private List<Account> accounts;
}
```

I hope it gets clear now.

And the [spring-mongodb documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/pdf/spring-data-mongodb-reference.pdf) section 4.6

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. i'm not tyring to change id serialization behavior. I'm trying to enforce how other fields are being serialized. for example i want that photoId will be serialized as objectId (as id of course). also i'm not sure i understand what u mean by "do you really want that"? can you argue that saving data as objectId is more expensive than saving it as string? (both location and performance wise?)

Comment: So you want to have 2 ObjectIds in each Document? - Why should you want that? The information in the default ObjectId can be relevant if you make any use of it. - For example when a this record created. spring-mongodb does only convert a field in _id to an ObjectId if it is of some type. (by default)

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/. If i wasn't clear photoId is reference to other document...i'm not trying to create a new objectId just serialize the String rep of photoId into it's objectId rep

Comment: Now it gets clear. look in the spring-mongodb documentation, link in my answer and search for `DBRef`. - I also updated my answer.

Comment: not looking for dbrefs... but manual referencing...i'm already doing manual referncing...My Question was not about it at all, i was just trying to clarify for you why i want it (even though it's not really important).. my question was how to make mongoTemplate save string field (where the string = objectId.toString() _ as object id and that is it

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I could find out is to make the type of photoId as String in MongoDB. If you are trying to assign an objectId value to the field in mongo shell, convert the objectId to string first :

```
var photoId = db.photo.insertOne({name : "xyz.png"}).insertedId
db.example.insertOne({
    photoId : photoId.str //<-- Changed objectId to string
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution to generate ObjectId programmatically in Java code using org.bson.types.ObjectId class:

```
String newId = ObjectId.get().toString();

// Our order entity in payment system needs a different id for external usage, for security reasons.
order.setExternalOrderId(newId);
```

But still wondering whether it is possible to use MongoDB to auto generate the ObjectId for us. So far no luck.